# Hive action fails on Oozie, while works well on hive commandline

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

Here is my workflow, works well if I have sample SQL like show tables or drop partition(Tried with Tez as well, it fials with cryptic error message again)..

```
workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="UDEX-OOZIE POC">
  <credentials>
    <credential name="HiveCred" type="hcat">
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
        <value>thrift://xxxx.local:9083</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
        <value>hive/_HOST@xxxx.LOCAL</value>
      </property>
    </credential>
  </credentials>
  <start to="IdEduTranCell-pm"/>
  <action name="IdEduTranCell-pm" cred="HiveCred">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.5">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <job-xml>${HiveConfigFile}</job-xml>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>default</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
      <script>${IdEduTranCell_path}</script>
      <param>SOURCE_DB_NAME=${SOURCE_DB_NAME}</param>
      <param>STRG_DB_NAME=${STRG_DB_NAME}</param>
      <param>TABLE_NAME=${TABLE_NAME}</param>
      <file>${IdEduTranCell_path}#${IdEduTranCell_path}</file>
      <file>${HiveConfigFile}#${HiveConfigFile}</file>
    </hive>
    <ok to="sub-workflow-end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="kill">
    <message>Sub-workflow failed while loading data into hive tables, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="sub-workflow-end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

But fails for a SQL . Data is not too large(fails for even 1 record), so something wrong that i cant spot on log.. please help

```
INSERT OVERWRITE  TABLE  xxx1.fact_tranCell
PARTITION (Timestamp)
   select
     `(Timestamp)?+.+`, Timestamp as Timestamp
   from xxx2.fact_tranCell
   order by tranCell_ID,ADMIN_CELL_ID, SITE_ID;
```

SQL is not bad, runs fine on command line..

```
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1459756606292_15271)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      7          7        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 3 ......   SUCCEEDED     10         10        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 03/03  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 19.72 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading data to table xxx1.fact_trancell partition (timestamp=null)
         Time taken for load dynamic partitions : 496
        Loading partition {timestamp=1464012900}
         Time taken for adding to write entity : 8
Partition 4g_oss.fact_trancell{timestamp=1464012900} stats: [numFiles=10, numRows=4352, totalSize=9660382, rawDataSize=207776027]
OK
Time taken: 34.595 seconds
```

--------------------------- LOG ----------------------------

```
Starting Job = job_1459756606292_15285, Tracking URL = hxxp://xxxx.local:8088/proxy/application_1459756606292_15285/
Kill Command = /usr/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1459756606292_15285
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2016-05-27 17:32:35,792 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-05-27 17:32:51,692 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 9.97 sec
2016-05-27 17:33:02,263 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 14.97 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 14 seconds 970 msec
Ended Job = job_1459756606292_15285
Launching Job 2 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1459756606292_15286, Tracking URL = hxxp://xxxx.local:8088/proxy/application_1459756606292_15286/
Kill Command = /usr/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1459756606292_15286
Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2016-05-27 17:33:16,583 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-05-27 17:33:29,814 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.29 sec
2016-05-27 17:33:45,587 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 38.74 sec
2016-05-27 17:33:53,990 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.29 sec
2016-05-27 17:34:08,662 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 39.27 sec
2016-05-27 17:34:17,061 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.29 sec
2016-05-27 17:34:28,576 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 38.28 sec
2016-05-27 17:34:36,940 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.29 sec
2016-05-27 17:34:48,435 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 38.09 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 38 seconds 90 msec
Ended Job = job_1459756606292_15286 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://xxxx.local:8088/proxy/application_1459756606292_15286/
Examining task ID: task_1459756606292_15286_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1459756606292_15286

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_1459756606292_15286_r_000000

URL:
  hxxp://xxxx.local:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1459756606292_15286&tipid=task_1459756606292_15286_r_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: Java heap space

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 14.97 sec   HDFS Read: 87739161 HDFS Write: 16056577 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-2: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 38.09 sec   HDFS Read: 16056995 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 53 seconds 60 msec
Intercepting System.exit(2)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [2]
```

I could see the error in the log is while writing the ORC files, strange the ORC files are written nicely form command line !!!!

```
2016-05-30 11:11:20,377 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: FS[1]: records written - 1
2016-05-30 11:11:21,307 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: FS[1]: records written - 10
2016-05-30 11:11:21,917 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: FS[1]: records written - 100
2016-05-30 11:11:22,420 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: FS[1]: records written - 1000
2016-05-30 11:11:24,181 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExtractOperator: 0 finished. closing...
2016-05-30 11:11:24,181 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: 1 finished. closing...
2016-05-30 11:11:24,181 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: FS[1]: records written - 4352
2016-05-30 11:11:33,028 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OutStream.getNewInputBuffer(OutStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OutStream.write(OutStream.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.writeDirectValues(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.writeValues(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.write(RunLengthIntegerWriterV2.java:762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StringTreeWriter.flushDictionary(WriterImpl.java:1211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StringTreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:1132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StructTreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:1616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushStripe(WriterImpl.java:1996)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:2288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.close(OrcOutputFormat.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator$FSPaths.closeWriters(FileSinkOperator.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.closeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:952)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:598)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.close(ExecReducer.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `hive-site.xml` accessed by your Hive command line is exactly the same as the one you push to the Oozie job?

Comment: And the `yarn-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml` etc. are exactly the same on the node you run Hive command-line, and on the nodes Oozie runs its Launcher container? Because the same job could succeed with a default container size of 2 GB and fail consistently with 512 MB. It could be even worse if the Java heap size limit is not aligned with the container size (i.e. silly OOM errors if heap limit arbitrarily too low, container getting killed by AM if heap limit is too high and runs over *cgroup* quota)